# My C with MQ receive a message return code 2037

Tags: c, ibm-mq

I run the C program, which connect to MQ and try to get a message from it. I always get a message:
         MQGET ended with reason code 2037
which means that MQ is not opened, but   MQOPEN CC=0 RC=0

MQ error log is empty.

**this is the program**

```
           #include <stdio.h>   
           #include <stdlib.h>      
           #include <string.h>      

           #include <cmqc.h>      /* includes for MQI*/              
           #include <cmqxc.h>   

           int main(int argc, char **argv)    
           {
           MQCNO   Connect_options = {MQCNO_DEFAULT};/MQNONNX opt*/   
           MQCD    ClientConn = {MQCD_CLIENT_CONN_DEFAULT};/*client channel*/  
           MQHCONN  Hcon;                   /* connection handle  */  
           MQHOBJ   Hobj;                   /* object handle */   
           MQLONG   CompCode;               /* completion code  */   
           MQLONG   OpenCode;               /* MQOPEN completion code*/  
           MQLONG   Reason;                 /* reason code    */   
           MQOD     od = {MQOD_DEFAULT};    /* Object Descriptor */   
           MQMD     md = {MQMD_DEFAULT};    /* Message Descriptor */   
           MQPMO    pmo = {MQPMO_DEFAULT};  /* put message options*/   
           MQLONG   O_options;              /* MQOPEN options  */   
           MQLONG   C_options;              /* MQCLOSE options */   
           MQGMO   gmo = {MQGMO_DEFAULT};   /* get message options */   

           char     QMgrName[MQ_Q_MGR_NAME_LENGTH+1];
           char     QName[MQ_Q_NAME_LENGTH+1];
           char     channelName[MQ_CHANNEL_NAME_LENGTH+1];
           char     hostname[1024];
           char     port[4];
           MQLONG   buflen;        /* buffer length*/
           char TempBuf[65536];
           int msgsToGet;
           int msgsGot;

           if (argc != 6)   
           {   
            printf("Usage: MQTest11 QMgrName ChlName hostname port  QName\n");   
            return(1);   
           }    

           **/* copy MQ manager name */**   
           strncpy(QMgrName, argv[1], MQ_Q_MGR_NAME_LENGTH);    
           QMgrName[MQ_Q_MGR_NAME_LENGTH] = '\0';    

           **/* copy channel name */**
           strncpy(channelName, argv[2], MQ_CHANNEL_NAME_LENGTH);    
           channelName[MQ_CHANNEL_NAME_LENGTH] = '\0';    

           **/* copy hostname */**
           strncpy(hostname, argv[3], 1023);    
           hostname[1023] = '\0'; 

           **/* copy port number */**   
           strncpy(port,argv[4],4);    
           strncpy(QName, argv[5], MQ_Q_NAME_LENGTH);    
           QName[MQ_Q_NAME_LENGTH] = '\0';    

           **/* copy hostname for connection */**
           strncpy(ClientConn.ConnectionName,hostname, MQ_CONN_NAME_LENGTH);    

           **/* copy channel name */**
           strncpy(ClientConn.ChannelName,channelName,MQ_CHANNEL_NAME_LENGTH);   

           **/* Point the MQCNO to the client connection definition */**   
           Connect_options.ClientConnPtr = &ClientConn;    
           Connect_options.Version = MQCNO_VERSION_2;    

           **/* use MQCONNX */**    

           if (CompCode == MQCC_FAILED)    
           {   
                /* exit with print the reason */    
           }    
           else    
           {    
            strncpy(od.ObjectName, QName, (size_t)MQ_Q_NAME_LENGTH);    
            O_options = MQOO_OUTPUT + MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;    
            MQOPEN(Hcon,                      /* connection handle  */   
            &od,                       /* object descriptor for queue  */   
            O_options,                 /* open options                 */   
            &Hobj,                     /* object handle                */   
            &OpenCode,                 /* MQOPEN completion code       */   
            &Reason);                  /* reason code                  */   

            printf("MQTest11 MQOPEN CC=%ld RC=%ld\n", CompCode, Reason);

            if (OpenCode == MQCC_OK)    /* if MQOPEN , then continue in the while loop */      
            {    
            gmo.Options = MQGMO_WAIT + MQGMO_CONVERT;    
            gmo.WaitInterval = 15000;    
            msgsGot = 0;    
            msgsToGet = 0;    
            CompCode = OpenCode;    
            }    
             while (CompCode != MQCC_FAILED && ((msgsToGet == 0) || (msgsGot < msgsToGet)))    
            {   

           /* define length of the buffer -1 */   
           buflen = strlen(TempBuf) - 1;    */ buffer length */
           memcpy(md.MsgId, MQMI_NONE, sizeof(md.MsgId)); /*copy msg ID*/     
           memcpy(md.CorrelId, MQCI_NONE, sizeof(md.CorrelId));/*copy corrlID*/      
           md.Encoding       = MQENC_NATIVE; /*encode*/   
           md.CodedCharSetId = MQCCSI_Q_MGR;   

           /* function to get message from MQ*/
           MQGET(Hcon,       /* get message from MQ */   
           Hobj,             /* object handle*/   
           &md,              /* message descriptor*/   
           &gmo,             /*get message options*/    
           buflen,           /*buffer length*/   
           TempBuf,          /* buffer */   
           &messlen,         /* message length*/   
           &CompCode,       /* completion code*/   
           &Reason);         /* reason code*/   

         **/* I put some statements to check if transaction failed or not*/**    
           if (Reason != MQRC_NONE)     
           {   
           if (Reason == MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE)   
           {   
           /* print statement no more messages */   
           else   
           {   
             printf("MQGET ended with reason code %d comcode %d\n",Reason,CompCode);       
            if (Reason == MQRC_TRUNCATED_MSG_FAILED)    
            {   
             /print statement that it is failed*/    
            }     
            }   
            }   

            **This is almost done, only statement if Compcode not failed, then print buffer**
```

I have changed char TempBuf declaration to MQBYTE and it is not help

Comment: To answer questions like this, we need to see the _smallest possible_, _complete program_, _that reproduces the problem_.  All three properties are required.  This is not that - you have left out key pieces and made changes that make the program syntactically invalid.  Please read and follow the instructions at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Comment: Most importantly, you seem to have replaced the calls to `MQCONNX` and `MQOPEN` in this program with placeholders.  We need to see those.  Also, every construct of the form `**/* comment */**` should be throwing syntax errors.

Comment: Please show your MQOPEN call.

Comment: Having said all that, I find the if-statement immediately after `/* use MQOPEN */` highly suspicious.  The comments make it sound like it was meant to print an error and exit the program when MQOPEN fails, but it doesn't actually do that, so you could be reaching the while loop anyway.

Comment: I added MQOPEN call, please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MQRC 2037 is MQRC_NOT_OPEN_FOR_INPUT, you can find this information by running the mqrc command provided with the IBM MQ Client or server install, below is a sample output on a Linux server:

```
$ mqrc 2037

      2037  0x000007f5  MQRC_NOT_OPEN_FOR_INPUT
```

You do not show the MQOPEN call but if it is using the `O_options`, it would be explained by this, you currently have the following:

```
O_options = MQOO_OUTPUT + MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
```

This should someing like the following:

```
O_options = MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF + MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
```

I would suggested that you review the sample applications provided with the IBM MQ install.  On Linux these would be located in `/opt/mqm/samp`.  The sample `amqsget0.c` would be similar to your program except it is using a MQCONN not MQCONNX.

Comment: I am ready to kiss you. I changed options, and it works perfectly. Great. you are so smart and helpful. Thank you very much. I owe you , what do you want? Vodka, Cognac, wine,restaurant, everything